# Regex to match various instances of time

Tags: javascript, regex

When trying to match these various styles of time, i.e.:

```
const str = `
  12) 9 p.m. A walk away

  06) Noon. Snack 

  4) 10:30 a.m. A stroll`;
```

To extract as:

`["9 p.m.", "Noon", "10:30 a.m."]`

I'm using this regex expression:

`/([0-1]?[0-9]|2[0-3]:[0-5]?[0-9] p.m.|a.m.|Noon)/g`

But `str.match()` is returning as:

`["12", "9", "06", "Noon", "4", "10", "3", "0", "a.m."]`

Is there an issue with the capture groupings?

Comment: Are you sure you want to match `18:30 p.m.` or `23:45 a.m.`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could match the hours and make the minutes part optional using `(?::[0-5][0-9])?`

In your pattern you use a single group for all the alternatives, where you want a group by itself to group a set of alternatives.

The part of a.m. and p.m. could be written as `[ap]\.m` (note to escape the dot to match it literally)

The whole outer group can be a non capturing group `(?:` from which you can take the match

To prevent a partial match, you could start the pattern with a word boundary `\b`

The pattern could be written as:

```
\b(?:(?:[01]?[0-9]|2[0-3])(?::[0-5][0-9])? [ap]\.m\.|Noon)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/iAmqsG/1)

If you want to match the 12h clock time:

```
\b(?:(?:1[0-2]|0?[1-9])(?::[0-5][0-9])? [ap]\.m\.|Noon)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/fRBQGB/1)

```js
const pattern = /\b(?:(?:[01]?[0-9]|2[0-3])(?::[0-5][0-9])? [ap]\.m\.|Noon)/g;
const str = `
  12) 9 p.m. A walk away

  06) Noon. Snack

  4) 10:30 a.m. A stroll`;

console.log(str.match(pattern));
```